# SAPUI5 with V4 - Batch reuests placed automatically without clicking on SAVE button

Tags: sapui5, odata-v4, sap-cap

I have an issue in my SAPUI5 project using V4 Model. Everytime I change a value in the input field, a  batch request is placed automatically changing the value in the backend. We want to send all changes upon clicking SAVE button. Can you please tell what is that I am missing?

Regards,
Phani.

Comment: Is the app freestyle? Or is it based on SAP Fiori elements?

Comment: Have you seen the OData V4 topic [Batch Control](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/74142a38e3d4467c8d6a70b28764048f)?